# How can i try all possible combinations of a dataframe, but mantaining the order of row items, in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, combinations, python-itertools

As the title goes,i have to maintain the order of row items , so , something as "combinations" from itertools doesn't actually help

what this means, if you think about it, is that we have to shift the space between items in columns to  have different combinations that don't change order.
example:

From This:

```python
     MON       TUE         WED         THU   ...
0   bread    chocolate    wine     chocolate ...
1   pizza    bread        bread    chocolate ...
2   bread    pizza        bread    apple     ...
3   wine     bread        apple    wine      ...
```

I want to try all possible combinations of this dataframe changing the distance with one and another item, of course with a maximum else it will just add infinite spaces inbetween...

```
     MON       TUE         WED         THU    FRI      SAT        SUN   ...
0   bread     NaN         chocolate   NaN     NaN      wine       NaN   ...
1   NaN       pizza       bread       bread   NaN      chocolate  NaN   ...
2   bread     NaN         pizza       bread   NaN      NaN        apple ...  
3   NaN       NaN         wine        bread   apple    wine       NaN   ...
```

So in this example output, spaces have been inserted between row items ,most likely with a "for" or something,that tries different number of spaces between them,but that's what i'm searching for;just can't figure out the right algorithm.

Any help? D:  .Thank you in advance and sorry if i'm missing something very stupid :C.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately your question is unclear. How do those input values map to those output values? From what you've posted it looks like you just placed  `NaN` values in between the real values at random. What constitutes "all combinations" in your use case for, for example, row 0?

Comment: i'll try to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm clear on what you're looking to do, but I think this might be it.

```
# setup mock dataframe
meals_df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"MON": "bread", "TUE": "chocolate", "WED": "wine", "THU": "chocolate"},
    {"MON": "pizza", "TUE": "bread", "WED": "bread", "THU": "chocolate"},
    {"MON": "bread", "TUE": "pizza", "WED": "apple", "THU": "apple"},
    {"MON": "wine", "TUE": "bread", "WED": "apple", "THU": "wine"}
])

days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']

menus = list()

for ix, *meal_list in meals_df.itertuples():

    for days_combo in itertools.combinations(days, 4):
        menu = dict(zip(days_combo, meal_list))
        menus.append(menu)

df = pd.DataFrame(menus)
```

df output:

```
    Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
0   bread   chocolate   wine    chocolate   NaN NaN NaN
1   bread   chocolate   wine    NaN chocolate   NaN NaN
2   bread   chocolate   wine    NaN NaN chocolate   NaN
3   bread   chocolate   wine    NaN NaN NaN chocolate
4   bread   chocolate   NaN wine    chocolate   NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
135 NaN NaN wine    bread   apple   wine    NaN
136 NaN NaN wine    bread   apple   NaN wine
137 NaN NaN wine    bread   NaN apple   wine
138 NaN NaN wine    NaN bread   apple   wine
139 NaN NaN NaN wine    bread   apple   wine
140 rows × 7 columns
```

Comment: Wow! Totally answered! Thanks for your help brotha :3